# LARAVEL - Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

What's the problem? I have records in DB.

The ressource route is `Route::resource('dylan_dog', 'DylanDogController');`

I looped each `$dylan_dog` record, provided by the controller(further below), in `index.blade.php` like this:

```
@foreach ($dylan_dog as $ddog)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $ddog -> id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $ddog -> name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $ddog -> title }}</td>
          <td>{{ $ddog -> biography }}</td>
          <td><a href="{{ route('dylan_dog.edit', $dylan_dog->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
          <td>
            <form action="{{ route('dylan_dog.destroy', $dylan_dog->id) }}" method="post">
              @csrf
              @method('DELETE')
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
```

What is the catch?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Dylan_dog;
class DylanDogController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
      $dylan_dog = Dylan_dog::all();

      return view('dylan_dog.index', compact('dylan_dog'));

    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
      return view('dylan_dog.create');
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'title'=> 'required',
        'biography' => 'required'
      ]);
      $dylan_dog = new Dylan_dog([
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'title'=> $request->get('title'),
        'biography'=> $request->get('biography')
      ]);
      $dylan_dog->save();
      return redirect('/dylan_dog')->with('success', 'Thanks for your contribution');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
      //return view('dylan_dog.index', ['name' => Dylan_dog::findOrFail($id)]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
      $dylan_dog = Dylan_dog::find($id);

      return view('dylan_dog.edit', compact('dylan_dog'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'title'=> 'required',
        'biography' => 'required'
      ]);

      $dylan_dog = Share::find($id);
      $dylan_dog->name = $request->get('name');
      $dylan_dog->title = $request->get('title');
      $dylan_dog->biography = $request->get('biography');
      $dylan_dog->save();

      return redirect('/dylan_dog')->with('success', 'Character has been updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
      $dylan_dog = Share::find($id);
      $dylan_dog->delete();

      return redirect('/dylan_dog')->with('success', 'Character has been deleted successfuly');
    }

}
```

> Error message "ErrorException (E_ERROR) Property [id] does not exist
>   on this collection instance. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\miljan\resources\views\dylan_dog\index.blade.php)"

Comment: hello, Could you please dd($ddog)?

Comment: Here:
"{{ route('dylan_dog.edit', $dylan_dog->id) }}" 
{{ route('dylan_dog.destroy', $dylan_dog->id) }}
you are using the collection not the model

Comment: as @Oddball said, you have some `$dylan_dog->id` that should be `$ddog->id` in your blade

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed you are using `$dylan_dog->id`. `$dylan_dog` is a `Collection` and doesn't have `id` as attribute.Change it to `$ddog->id`:

```
<td><a href="{{ route('dylan_dog.edit', $ddog->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
      <td>
        <form action="{{ route('dylan_dog.destroy', $ddog->id) }}" method="post">
          @csrf
          @method('DELETE')
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
        </form>
      </td>
```

You should change the route paramters aswell to $dogg.